# xmlstarlet replace xml node value

Tags: xmlstarlet

I'm new using xmlstarlet.  I'd like to know how to change the value of xml node using  xmlstarlet.

I tried something.
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/file_input/uri'  'string("s3://my_source")' template.xml > output.xml

doesn't work.

My expected output as  **s3://my_source** and **s3://mydestination**. I'd like to change **source_path** and **destination_path** node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job version="2.10.8">
  <input>
    <deblock_enable>Auto</deblock_enable>
    <deblock_strength>0</deblock_strength>
    <no_psi>false</no_psi>
    <order>1</order>
    <timecode_source>zerobased</timecode_source>
    <file_input>
      <certificate_file nil="true"/>
      <password>upass</password>
      <uri>source_path</uri>
      <username>uname</username>
    </file_input>
    <file_group_settings>
      <rollover_interval nil="true"/>
      <destination>
        <password>upass</password>
        <username>uname</username>
        <uri>destination_path</uri>
      </destination>
    </file_group_settings>
  </input>
</job>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
           --update "//job/input/file_input/uri" \
           --value 's3://my_source' \
           --update "//job/input/file_group_settings/destination/uri" \
           --value 's3://mydestination' file.xml
```

If you want to edit file.xml inplace, add option `-L`.

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit --help`

Comment: Hi cryus,  My apologies that I did not write back to you earlier, I forgot to ask to add insert new line.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392564/xmlstarlet-append-and-insert-new-line-value