# xmlstarlet append and insert new line value

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'd like to know how to add a new line using xmlstarlet.

My aim is to add a `<audio>track_01</audio>` after **job/input/file_input/uri.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job version="2.10.8">
  <input>
    <deblock_enable>Auto</deblock_enable>
    <deblock_strength>0</deblock_strength>
    <no_psi>false</no_psi>
    <order>1</order>
    <timecode_source>zerobased</timecode_source>
    <file_input>
      <certificate_file nil="true"/>
      <password>upass</password>
      <uri>source_path</uri>
      <username>uname</username>
    </file_input>
    <file_group_settings>
      <rollover_interval nil="true"/>
      <destination>
        <password>upass</password>
        <username>uname</username>
        <uri>destination_path</uri>
      </destination>
    </file_group_settings>
  </input>
</job>
```

How can I insert new line using the below code?

```
xmlstarlet edit \
           --update "//job/input/file_input/uri" \
           --value 's3://my_source' \
           --update "//job/input/file_group_settings/destination/uri" \
           --value 's3://mydestination' file.xml
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to append (`--append`) after the desired node/element a new element (`--type elem`) with name audio (`--name "audio"`) and value (`--value "track_01"`):

```
xmlstarlet edit \
           --update "//job/input/file_input/uri" \
           --value 's3://my_source' \
           --update "//job/input/file_group_settings/destination/uri" \
           --value 's3://mydestination' \
           --append "//job/input/file_input/uri" \
           --type elem --name "audio" --value "track_01" file.xml
```

If you want to edit file.xml inplace, add option `-L`.

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit --help`