# sed command to replace text from some search position

Tags: sed

I want to replace value 2000 with 5000 for the fruit grapes. How to use sed to start searching from 'grapes' position and replace the first occurance

```
<fruits>
   <fruit>
        <name>apple</name>
        <value>2000</value>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
        <name>grapes</name>
        <value>2000</value>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
        <name>banana</name>
        <value>2000</value>
   </fruit>
</fruits>
```

I tried

> `sed '\,grapes, s/2000/5000/' fruits.txt`

Comment: this is more suitable for tools like xmlstarlet than sed, also while asking a question please make sure to add what you have tried yourself to solve it

Comment: updated with what i tried, basically i have to update a jenkins job config file (the above is just an example) where i can only use unix commands

Comment: Use `xmlstarlet`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/46392888/1331399 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390596/1331399

Comment: xmlstarlet is not available in unix machine that jenkins is installed

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '\%<name>grapes</name>%,\%</fruit>%s%<value>2000</value>%<value>5000</value>%' fruits.xml
```

We use the generalized `\%` to avoid needing to backslash the slash in the closing tags.  The `s%%%` doesn't need to be backslashed because `sed` already knows that the thing after `s` is the separator.

On *BSDish platforms, including MacOS, you need an explicit empty string argument to `sed -i` before the script itself (so `sed -i '' '\%...'`)

This tries to be strict, but of course cannot cope with all the possible variations which are syntactically allowed in XML. If your file is always in exactly the expected format, this should work for now.  One of the drawbacks is that you will get no warning when it stops working because Jenkins decides to start using whitespace inside the tags, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Using xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//fruits/fruit/name[.='grapes']/following-sibling::value" -v 5000 fruits.xml
```

This will update (`ed -u`) the xml by selecting the xpath `//fruits/fruit/name` where `name` is `grapes` and where the `following-sibling` is `value`, changing the content to `5000`.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for doing s/old/new **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '/grapes/{f=1} f && sub(/2000/,"5000"){f=0} 1' file
<fruits>
   <fruit>
        <name>apple</name>
        <value>2000</value>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
        <name>grapes</name>
        <value>5000</value>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
        <name>banana</name>
        <value>2000</value>
   </fruit>
</fruits>
```